# cURL to Rails "-d" format conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, curl, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I'm working with the STRAVA api and a gem built off of it. The command I'm trying to do is:

```
$ curl -G https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/explore \
-H "Authorization: Bearer 83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9" \
-d bounds=37.821362,-122.505373,37.842038,-122.465977 \
```

How do I format my ruby on rails command to make the request. Currently:

```
@client.segment_explorer([37.821362,-122.505373,37.842038,-122.465977])
```

The source code for the api gem looks like this:

```
    def segment_explorer(args = {}, options = {}, &block)
      # Fetches the connections for given object.
      api_call('segments/explore', args, 'get', options, &block)
    end
```

How would I pass the "-d" as a longitude into this method to successful create an api call?

Answer (score 0):

Which gem are you using? I did a quick search, and couldn't find the code you refer to anywhere. However, at a guess, you might want to try passing through a hash of arguments, where they key is the same name as the URL parameter.

For example:

```
@client.segment_explorer({
    bounds: "37.821362,-122.505373,37.842038,-122.465977"
})
```

If that doesn't work, can you provide a link to the gem you're using?